# Textbox does not populate with database values when hyperlink is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I run the page, and click on the value in the partial table nothing happens with the onclick event. the values are not populating on the textboxes.I set the style of the anchor element to cursor: pointer. Debugging the code as shown in the images, the values populate correctly they just do not appear in the textboxes.

index.cshtml

```
@page "{id?}"
@model IndexModel

@{ViewData["Title"] = "Test";}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="display-4">@Model.PageTitle</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mt-0" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 offset-1" id="ApplicationResult">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" id="ApplicationOwnerResult">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3" id="ApplicationDmvResult">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mt-0" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Date of birth" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DateOfBirth">
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Driver's License Number:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Driver's license number" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DriversLicenseNumber">
                    <span asp-validation-for="DriversLicenseNumber"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1 offset-5" type="submit" id="Submit" disabled asp-page-handler="Submit">Submit</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1" type="button" id="Reset" onclick="clearAll()">Reset</button>
            </div>
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script>
// Any exemption applications found will be displayed when the page initially loads. On POST request GET form will be hidden
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ("@Model.Exist" == "DivIsVisible") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Index/?handler=Display",
                type: "GET",
                data: { value: @Model.Id },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function (data) { $("#ApplicationResult").html(data); }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#ApplicationResult").hide();
        }
    });

// autofill the inputs
    function displayOwnerInfo(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value=" + id,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) { $("#DateOfBirth").val(data.DateOfBirth); $("#DriversLicenseNumber").val(data.DriversLicenseNumber); }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

index.cshtml.cs

```
using DMVServiceReference;
using DMV.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DMV.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public Assess50Context _context;

        // Id property refers to checking the PropertyId value for the URL
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public int Id { get; set; }
        // Exist property refers to checking if GetDivs exist on POST request
        [BindProperty] public string PageTitle { get; set; } = "Residency Check";
        public ResidencyCheckCriteria CheckCriteria { get; set; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember, MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = " "), MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = " "), RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{8}$)", ErrorMessage = " "), Required(ErrorMessage = " ")] public string DateOfBirth { get => CheckCriteria.DateOfBirth; set => CheckCriteria.DateOfBirth = value; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember, MaxLength(13, ErrorMessage = " "), MinLength(13, ErrorMessage = " "), RegularExpression(@"^([A-Za-z0-9]{13}$)", ErrorMessage = " "), Required(ErrorMessage = " ")] public string DriversLicenseNumber { get => CheckCriteria.DriverLicenseNumber; set => CheckCriteria.DriverLicenseNumber = value; }
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public string Exist { get; set; } = "DivIsVisible";

        public IndexModel(Assess50Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
            CheckCriteria = new ResidencyCheckCriteria();
        }

        // Reads all exemption application table information by property id
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplay(int value) => Partial("_DisplayApplicationPartial", _context.ExemptionApplications.Where(x => x.PropertyId == value).ToList());

        // Reads all exemption application owner information by exemption application id
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayOwner(int value) => Partial("_DisplayOwnerPartial", _context.ExemptionApplicationOwners.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationId == value).GroupBy(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());

        // Reads the dmv information by application owner ID
        // public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo(int value) => Partial("_DisplayDMVPartial", _context.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value).ToList());
        public JsonResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo(int value)
        {
            ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation data = _context.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value).First();
            return new JsonResult(new { DateOfBirth = data.DmvDob.ToString(), DriversLicenseNumber = data.DriverLicense });
        }
```

DbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class Assess50Context : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplication> ExemptionApplications { get; set; } = null!;
  public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation> ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations { get; set; } = null!;
 public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplicationOwner> ExemptionApplicationOwners { get; set; } = null!;

 public Assess50Context() {}

        public Assess50Context(DbContextOptions<Assess50Context> options) : base(options) {}

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
  }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Application.cs model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplication
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Year")] public short YearId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "App ID")] public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Reference Number")] public string? ApplicationReference { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Owner.cs model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplicationOwner
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Application Owner ID")] public int ExemptionApplicationOwnerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Owner ID")] public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]public string? AssessProName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DmvInformation.cs model

```
using SoapCore.ServiceModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationOwnerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "DOB")] public DateTime? DmvDob { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Driver's License #")] public string? DriverLicense { get; set; }
    }
}
```

_DisplayApplicationPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplication>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <div id="ExemptionApplicationNav">
        <table class="PartialTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="PartialTableRowData" colspan="3">Exemption Applications</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.YearId)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ApplicationReference)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ExemptionApplicationId)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplication item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">@item.YearId</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">@item.ApplicationReference</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">
                            <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" href="Index/?handler=DisplayOwner&value=@item.ExemptionApplicationId">@item.ExemptionApplicationId</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 }
else
{
    <p>No exemption applications found for this Property ID</p>
}
    <script>
        $('#ExemptionApplicationNav a').click(function (e) {
            $('#ApplicationOwnerResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
                $('#ApplicationOwnerResult').show()
            })
            return false
        })
    </script>
```

_DisplayOwnerPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="OwnerNav">
        <table class="PartialTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="PartialTableRowData" colspan="3">Owner Information</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData" colspan="2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AssessProName)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">
                           <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" onclick="displayOwnerInfo('@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId')">@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId</a>
                      <!-- <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" href="Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value=@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId">@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId</a> -->
                        </td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowMultipleData">@item.FirstName</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowMultipleData">@item.LastName</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No owner data available</p>
}
 <!--
    <script>
        $('#OwnerNav a').click(function (e) {
              $('#ApplicationDmvResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
                  $('#ApplicationDmvResult').show()
              })
              return false
        })
    </script>
-->
```

_DisplayDMVPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="DmvNav">
        <table style=" border: 1px solid black;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">DMV Information</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DmvDob)</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DriverLicense)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">item.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy")</td> -->
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">@item.DmvDob</td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">@item.DriverLicense</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No owner data available</p>
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your ajax in the Index.cshtml like below:

```
// autofill the inputs
    function displayOwnerInfo(id) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value=" + id,
    type: "GET",    
    success: function (data) { 
    $("#DateOfBirth").val(data.dateOfBirth);                     
    $("#DriversLicenseNumber").val(data.driversLicenseNumber);                 
    }
```

resut:
[image]

Comment: @TheGame1083    Change into lowercase like   `val(data.dateOfBirth);  ` You are all uppercase and I am all lowercase. Besides, I use the code like Rena's.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts in Partials which are themselves loaded by script will not execute. You should place the code that adds the click event handler to the `#OwnerNav a` element(s) to *Index.cshtml*. However, you need to use the [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method and apply it to an element that exists when the page is initially rendered (e.g. 'body'), passing in the target selector after the name of the event handler:

```
$('body').on('click', '#OwnerNav a', function (e) {
    //
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I attempted what you posted but the values still do not populate. Here is what I did based on your suggestion

`$('body').on('click', '#OwnerNav a', function DisplayInfo(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value=" + e,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#DateOfBirth").val(data.DateOfBirth);
                    $("#DriversLicenseNumber").val(data.DriversLicenseNumber);
                }
            });
        })`

Comment: @Chen can you take a look?

Comment: @Qing Guo your answer is the same as what I have already tried and it still does not work. can you please edit your answer to provide your full code so  I can see